# Storing latitude and longitude in CSV file every 15 minutes

Tags: android, csv, gps

I want to access users location i.e latitude and longitude in every 15 minutes and store them in a CSV file. How can I do this?

I have a `GPSTracker` class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 15; // 15 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
```

and in `MainActivity`:

```
  File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File gpxfile = new File(root, "mydata.csv");
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writeCsvHeader("DateTime", "Latitude", "Longitude");
        writeCsvData(""+strDate,latitude,longitude);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  private void writeCsvHeader(String h1, String h2, String h3) throws IOException {
    String line = String.format("%s,%s,%s\n", h1,h2,h3);
    writer.write(line);
}
private void writeCsvData(String date, double lat, double lon) throws IOException {
    String line = String.format("%s,%f,%f\n", date, lat, lon);
    writer.write(line);
}
```

for CSV I have referenced
http://antipastohw.pbworks.com/w/page/41913616/Write%20CSV%20files%20onto%20SD%20Card%20Storage

Comment: U can use timer and timer task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May this way possible**

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        Handler mnhandler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mnhandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //Use ur method which store CSV file 

                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, start, duration);
```

Comment: yes this works in background even if u want to run it when app is not closed then use Alarmmanager

Answer (score 1):

For doing an repetitive task you can use Handler like,

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // get Location or do whatever you want
            }
        }, (15 * 60 * 1000));
```

In this case getLocation() will call after every 15 min.